# Isomorphic quotient modules implies equal submodules?

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with unity $M$ an $R$-module and $N,L$ submodules of $M$ with $N\subseteq L$.

$$M/N\cong M/L\implies N=L\ ?$$

Comment: Is the isomorphism the canonical isomorphism?

Comment: I didn't consider that case. But if it is canonical, the statement seems true.

Comment: It  *is* true in that case, because you can use the *snake lemma*.

Comment: What I think is to show $L\subset N$. Let $l\in L$. Then $l+N\mapsto l+L=0$. Since the isomorphism is injective $l+N=0$ and $l\in N$.

Comment: It's  works  fine in that case and avoids having to ,use the snake lemma, which is indeed  a bit too much for suxh a situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not true. Consider (the $\Bbb Z$-module) $M=\Bbb Z\times\Bbb Z\times \cdots$, and the two submodules $N=\langle(1,0,0,\ldots)\rangle$ and $L=\langle(1,0,0,\ldots), (0,1,0,0,\ldots)\rangle$. Then $M\cong M/N\cong M/L$, but $N$ and $L$ are not only unequal, they aren't even isomorphic.

Comment: Thank you very much for the counter example!

Comment: @user682705 I think, if $R$ is noetherian and $M$ is finitely generated, then $N$ will turn out to equal $L$. Not entirely sure, though.

Comment: @Arthur $M$ finitely generated is enough to conclude that $N=L$.